# Payload for attributeGroups/{groupId}/attributeSetDefinitions MC API endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, marketingcloudapi, attribute-group

I'm trying to figure out how to create Attribute Groups and link them to data extensions via the Marketing Cloud REST API (and SOAP API for data extensions, if needed).

I managed to create an empty Attribute Group using the `{/contacts/v1/attributeGroups/}` endpoint. Digging around various available endpoints, I came to an understanding, that the main content of Attribute Groups - linked data extensions, are being stored in `attributeSetDefinitions`, which seem to include references to the Attribute Group and the Data Extension. (It's not immediately visible in `{/contacts/v1/attributeSetDefinitions/}`, but the response from the undocumented endpoint `{/hub/v1/contacts/schema/setDefinitions/{definitionID}}` returns a `storageReferenceID`, which directly references the Data Extension).

I discovered two endpoints for the creation of attribute set definitions - `{/hub/v1/contacts/schema/setDefinitions}` and 
`{/contacts/v1/attributeGroups/{groupId}/attributeSetDefinitions}`. I've experimented with various payloads but didn't manage to send a correct request for any of them.

Any tips on how the payload should look like? Or, is there any object I should create beforehand, and that's why my requests fail?

Comment: Deployment manager now allows you to create attribute groups, you may find some clue there in the json it downloads